# What is the differential Value-at-Risk?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, mathematics, value-at-risk, machine-learning, derivation

I am currently working on a Machine Learning Project, implementing portfolio optimization  algorithms according to different risk measures. I have found sufficient information on Sharpe Ratio optimisation, but not on Value-at-Risk.

My question is: What is the equation for differential VaR - the derivative taken with respect to a first-order exponential moving average decay rate?

It should be comparable to the differential Sharpe Ratio proposed by Moody & Safell. This formula was already discussed in: [What’s the derivative of the sharpe ratio for one asset? Trying to optimize on it for a model](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37969/what-s-the-derivative-of-the-sharpe-ratio-for-one-asset-trying-to-optimize-on-i)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking for something like this?

$\frac{d \mathrm{VaR}_q\left(Y+\lambda X\right)}{d\lambda}=E\left[X|Y+\lambda X=\mathrm{VaR}_q\left(Y+\lambda X\right)\right]$

Comment: Yes, thank you! I also found additional information I needed.